# I want to see the system log for a python program in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a Python program running in Ubuntu. The program is correct. But, somehow, it crashes. So, how do I see the log entry for the crash?

Note: A log entry is that which an Operating System keeps track of and gives a possible reason behind the crash.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some context. What log entry? Does the program create a log? Do you see anything printed on the terminal when it crashes? Did you write this program or is it someone else's?  How do you launch the program?

Comment: You seem to think the  "Operating System" automatically keeps track of the logs from your program. Why? Did you configure it to do so when starting your program? How?

Comment: I mean Operating System is for those purpose only.

Answer (score 0):

Installing [strace](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Strace) on ubuntu will help you debug your issue.

```
strace -Ff -tt <python program> 2>&1 | tee strace-<program>.log
```

See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Strace